# Extend a mixins script from vendor in Vuejs and Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

I have an original script (stripe.js) in my vendor file. Editing it directly in the vendor file is not a solution.

I wish I could change the function (createCardElement) I need.

```
/*stripe.js*/

module.exports = {
/**
 * The mixin's data.
 */
data() {
    return {
        stripe: Spark.stripeKey ? Stripe(Spark.stripeKey) : null
    }
},


methods: {
    /**
     * Create a Stripe Card Element.
     */
    createCardElement(container){
        if (!this.stripe) {
            throw "Invalid Stripe Key/Secret";
        }

        var card = this.stripe.elements().create('card', {
            hideIcon: false,
            hidePostalCode: true,
            style: {
                base: {
                    '::placeholder': {
                        color: '#aab7c4'
                    },
                    fontFamily: 'Whitney, Lato, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol"',
                    color: '#495057',
                    fontSize: '15px'
                }
            }
        });

        card.mount(container);

        return card;
    }
},
};
```

This file is imported into another file (register-stripe.js)

```
module.exports = {
    /**
     * Load mixins for the component.
     */
    mixins: [
        require('./../mixins/register'),
        require('./../mixins/plans'),
        require('./../mixins/vat'),
        require('./../mixins/stripe')
    ],
    selectedPlan(val){
                if (!val || val.price == 0) {
                    this.cardElement = null;
                    return;
                }

                if (!this.cardElement) {
                    this.$nextTick(()=> {
                        this.cardElement = this.createCardElement('#card-element');
                    });
                }
            }
        },
    }
```

I have access to a file or I can overwrite the functions in register-stripe.js, but I do not know how to overwrite those in the mixins array.

Register-stripe.js (version that I can edit)

```
var base = require('auth/register-stripe');

Vue.component('spark-register-stripe', {
    mixins: [base]
});
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to publish your Spark assets to do this. There's a command that Laravel includes as part of artisan which allows you to copy over any publishable files from a composer package into your project.

Spark makes use of this for its views, css, js and images. To publish the assets, browse to your project directory (where your `artisan` file is) and run:

`php artisan vendor:publish`

Depending on your Laravel and Spark version you'll either get:

- A list of available packages to import (in which case you just enter the number next to the package to import and hit enter)
- A list of files that have been imported from spark.

You can confirm if it has imported correctly by browsing to your resources/assets/js directory, where you should now have a `spark` and `spark-components` directory.

You'll find the stripe.js mixin file in `resources/assets/js/spark/mixins/ directory.